# Yammer API request error

Tags: yammer

I'm getting an 
    {"response":{"stat":"fail","code":17,"message":"Attempt to access a protected resource failed."}}
response on any request from some external yammer networks.

I'm doing a request with curl with access_token for that network in headers.

What's strange, it works fine with another external network, I've created myself from another account.

Comment: Similar thing reproduces with requests on client too.
When I'm trying to request data from my network - everying works fine.
And when I try to get data from the problem network - it fails with CORS error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/users.json?&_=1415878222370. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.